# Прошу помощи в определении правильной структуры хранения записей в MySQL

Tags: mysql, yii2, структуры-данных, relationship

Имеется единая форма, некоторые части формы отключаемые, в зависимости от надобности.

Схему в более качественном размере/масштабе можно увидеть по [ссылке](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tpqjyMeTeIF9xMV6zgyGoh-ft4C8LMvp/view?usp=sharing)

Основная проблема в том что, поездка может быть как в аэропорт, так и из аэропорта.
А так же поездка может быть типа точка-точка, то есть из определенного места до определенного места.
Может быть например одна остановка по пути следования, но не более одной.

Мне не понятно как организовать связи между таблицами.
Как должен хранится маршрут поездки, в одной таблице или же в разных таблицах.

Единственное что мне понятно, есть несколько справочных таблиц, они обозначены на схеме, а так же понятно что есть точки (адреса/location).

Есть так же мысль добавить в таблицу location метку типа точки, начальная, конечная, промежуточная.

> P.S. Схему начертил как смог, прошу не кидать помидорами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Основная проблема в том что, поездка может быть как в аэропорт, так и из аэропорта. А так же поездка может быть типа точка-точка, то есть из определенного места до определенного места. Может быть например одна остановка по пути следования, но не более одной.* Не усложняйте. наоборот, формализуйте. Есть узлы (точки - начальная, конечная, промежуточная), и есть направленные рёбра (движение от начальной до конечной точки отдельного сегмента). Маршрут может включать одно (начало->конец) или больше (начало->остановка и остановка->конец) рёбер, для удобства нумерованных.

Comment: *Есть так же мысль добавить в таблицу location метку типа точки, начальная, конечная, промежуточная.* Это атрибут не самой точки, а её как узла на маршруте. Но, поскольку такая "метка" однозначно определяется тем, является ли точка началом или концом ребра маршрута, она не нужна вообще.

Comment: @Akina можете подсказать библиотеку для хранения направленных ребер в MySQL ?

Comment: Какая библиотека? Вы о чём? Обычная таблица на два поля, плюс третье поле идентификатора маршрута, ну может ещё поле - синтетический ключ.

Comment: @Akina из того что вы написали выше я не понял ни слова к сожалению, не все такие одаренные как вы.

Comment: @Akina вы бы хотя бы написали название типа структуры для хранения или метода, но вы все такие умные, вам сложно написать например `edge-adjacency list`

Comment: Вы бы лучше написали ТЗ вместо структуры. Какие исходные данные у вас есть/будут и какая главная задача у этой системы? На сколько сложная логика работы будет? Планируется ли в будущем доработка или масштабирование системы? - от этого много зависит.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, итогом работы формы должен быть сохранённая в БД запись о заказе, плюс информация о маршруте.

В таком случае я предлагаю следующую базу данных для такого:

1. Таблица `order` (заказ, поездка, это основной домен):

   - `id` - `INT` или `UUID` - суррогатный ключ, идентификатор заказа
   - `route_id` - `INT` или `UUID` - ссылка на маршрут
   - `auto_id` - `INT` или `UUID` - ссылка на авто из справочника
   - ... ещё какие-нибудь поля из вашей формы
2. Таблица `address` - таблица с информацией о ваших адресах, в неё можно сохранять введённые пользователями адреса

   - `id` - `INT` или `UUID` - тоже суррогатный айди
   - `city`
   - `zip`
   - и так далее
3. Таблица `point` - таблица с точками маршрута

   - `order_id` - ссылка на таблицу `order`
   - `address_id` - ссылка на таблицу `address`
   - `position` - `INT` - порядковый номер точки на маршруте, типа 1, 2, 3 - 1 это точка отправления, 3 это точка прибытия, 2 это промежуточная

Связи между таблицами:

Один заказ - много точек
Один адрес - много точек

`order` <- `point` -> `address`

Таблицу `address` я выделил в отдельную, потому что скорее всего в будущем заказчик захочет выводить подсказки по адресам на форме. Данные адресов можно также скачать, например использовать официальную базу адресов КЛАДР или ту что новее, не помню её названия.

Поле формы "аэропорт" вы можете также брать из справочника, в котором будут значения "`airport_name`, `address_id`", связывающий аэропорт из формы с реальным адресом для создания из этого адреса запись в `point`.

Если же вы не хотиите, чтобы аэропорт был частью маршрута, можно добавить в таблицу `order` два поля:

`airport_id` - ссылка на справочник аэропортов
`direction` - направление следования, например `1` или `0` для "в аэропорт" или "из аэропорта", можно создать справочник `direction` в котором будут записи с описанием направления, и тогда уже сделать поле `order.direction_id` со ссылкой на справочник.

В общем, как поступать с "аэропорт" полем - лучше всего решать вам, я бы выбрал вариант с адресами, ибо тогда механизм построения маршрутов будет универсальный и в будущем можно будет как-то расширить модель данных, например, добавить кроме аэропортов вокзалы...